# Angular 2 Application with Spring Security and fetching data from Spring REST Service

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, rest, spring-security

I am working on an application architecture which will have independent UI Layer(HTML5 and Angular2)  and Service Layer(Spring Boot Project) . Both will be hosted on independent servers. The UI layer will fetch data from DB using REST Calls. I Have few queries.
1. I am building my UI with Angular2 which basically runs on node.js. How can i integrate spring security using ldap.
2. How can i make REST Calls to my service which is hosted on a different server.
3. How do i solve the issue of authentication/authorization with REST Service using Spring security.
Looking forward to your responses.
Thanks,
Avinash

Answer (score 1):

> 1. How can i integrate spring security using ldap.

Use Spring Security LDAP module to wire up the security services of your backend. Secure the URIs and that is all that you require.

[Spring LDAP Guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/authenticating-ldap/)

[Spring LDAP Reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/ldap.html)

> 2. How can i make REST Calls to my service which is hosted on a different server.

I presume that you will have the backend on a server and there is connectivity between your nodejs server and the backend server. Use the hostname and port if you want things to be simple. Please allow CORS on your backend server either programmatically, or by using a proxy server such as nginx.

> 3. How do i solve the issue of authentication/authorization with REST Service using Spring security.

Spring security will enable end points for Authentication and Authorization. Your angular application must need to check for the authentication at the start of every request ideally, and when there is a `(401) Authentication Failure`, redirect to a login controller. Keep the default route to the angular application to the login controller too.